# Is there an /etc/network/interfaces option like wireless-ap except for a wpa-ssid/wpa-psk connection?

Tags: linux, debian, networking, wifi, wpa-supplicant

In `/etc/network/interfaces` (on Debian Linux 7.6 with wpa_supplicant), wireless-ap forces a specific access point for wireless-essid connections.

Is there an equivalent option for wpa-ssid/wpa-psk connections to force a specific access point?

I'm looking for a hypothetical option like:

`wpa-ap 01:23:34:56:78:9A`

that would commit me to a particular access point out of a number of access points that all use the same wpa-ssid. The closest option like this is wireless-ap but it doesn't work for wpa connections.

Answer (score 1):

In order to configure wpa_supplicant to connect to a specific network:

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Have the file content look something like:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="network-name"
    psk="network-password"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP TKIP
    group=CCMP TKIP
}
```

Now you should be able to bring down / up the interface using

```
sudo ifdown wlan0
sudo ifup wlan0
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the option that you are looking for is `wpa-bssid`.

From (the surprisingly well hidden) `/usr/share/doc/wpasupplicant/README.Debian.gz`:

```
Table of Common Options
=======================

A brief summary of common 'wpa-' options that may be used in the
/etc/network/interfaces stanza for a wireless device. See the
'Important Notes About Managed Mode' section for information about
valid and invalid 'wpa-' values.

NOTE: ALL values are CASE SeNsItVe

Element        Example Value            Description
=======        =============            ===========
wpa-ssid       plaintextstring          sets the ssid of your network

wpa-bssid      00:1a:2b:3c:4d:5e        the bssid of your AP

wpa-psk        0123456789......         your preshared wpa key. Use
                                        wpa_passphrase(8) to generate your psk
                                        from a passphrase and ssid pair
    
wpa-key-mgmt   NONE, WPA-PSK, WPA-EAP,  list of accepted authenticated key
               IEEE8021X                management protocols
```

(The list continues.)

Hope this helps.